# How to handle the Amchart 4 cursor height?

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

How to make the Amchart 4 cursor height dynamic based on the series shape?

> It is working on Amchart 3

**v3:** Stopped on the selected value or on the bullets (That is what I need) property name "limitToGraph"

[image]

**V4:** Height 100% and overflow the bullets

[image]

So any Idea how to handle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify series to which cursor must be snapped:

```
chart.cursor.snapToSeries = series;
```

https://www.amcharts.com/demos/date-based-data/